# Determine display columns from Saved Search via SuiteTalk / NetSuite?

Tags: python, netsuite, zeep, suitetalk

I'm using Python 2.7 and [Zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) to call SuiteTalk [v2017_2_0](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_2_0/netsuite.wsdl), the SOAP-based NetSuite web service API. The command I'm running is `search` like so:

```
from zeep import Client
netsuite = Client(WSDL)

TransactionSearchAdvanced = netsuite.get_type(
    'ns19:TransactionSearchAdvanced')
TransactionSearchRow = netsuite.get_type('ns19:TransactionSearchRow')

# login removed for brevity

r = netsuite.service.search(TransactionSearchAdvanced(
    savedSearchId=search, columns=TransactionSearchRow()))
```

Now the results of this include all the data I want but I can't figure out how (if at all) I can determine the display columns that the website would show for this saved search and the order they go in.

I figure I could probably `netsuite.service.get()` and pass the `internalId` of the saved search but what type do I specify? Along those lines, has anyone found a decent reference for all the objects, type enumerations, etc.?

Comment: Hi Neil, have you figured the question out? Thanks,

Comment: No, I assume that the website stores preferences information somewhere that the API is not privy to. Perhaps in user preferences? So unfortunately I ended up hard-coding the column order on my application to match

Comment: or you can try this: https://github.com/jjorissen52/netsuite (I'm working on it and trying to find some clues)

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257412/1807800

Check out the above link regarding Search Preferences. It explains how to limit columns returned to those only in the search.

Comment: This limits the columns returned but what I'm looking for is a *list* of those columns and in the order they would occur on the website (e.g. how they're configured in the saved search)

Comment: Neil - Did we get any information on this? I am also looking for same information